# Where is my mistake? Algbraic manipulation of a term of Fourier tranfoms delivers zero.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We have the following equality given (derived in the paper itself "[**A Donsker theorem for Levy measures**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0590)")$(p.16,4.9)$:

$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\Big]=
\frac1{i\bullet}\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\big(\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big)'\Big]\tag1
$$
where $\mathcal F$ denotes the inverse Fourier transform and $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of a probability law, with $\varphi^{-1}\equiv\frac1{\varphi}$.

Unfortunately it is not explained in the text, but I am rather sure, the $\bullet$ is just a place holder for the argument of the function - so we actually have
 $$
\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\Big](x)=
\frac1{ix}\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\big(\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big)'\Big](x)\tag2
$$
which also blends in with the known "derivative of the Fourier argument".

Now comes the term which seems to vanish, though this can't be, since otherwise the whole paper would be pointless - therefore from now on I assume I am wrong, we have:

In the first step we have: $(\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big)'=-(\varphi^{-1})' (-u)$ and hence
from $(2)$ we get 
 $$
\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\Big](x)=
\frac1{ix}\mathcal F^{-1}\Big[\big(\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big)'\Big](x)=-\frac1{ix}F^{-1}\Big[(\varphi^{-1})'(-u)\Big](x)\tag3
$$
and it follows then by plugging in ($p.13,(4.2)$)
\begin{align}
&\frac1{ i\Delta}\int_{\mathbb R}\big( \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\mathcal F[g](u)\mathcal{F}[K_h](-u) \big](x)ix +  \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[ (\varphi^{-1})'(-u)F[g](u)\mathcal{F}[K_h](-u) \big](x)  \big)\;P(dx)\\
&=\frac1{ i\Delta}\int_{\mathbb R}\Big(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big]*g*K_h)(x)ix+\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[(\varphi^{-1})'(-u)\big]*g*K_h)P(x)\Big)P(dx)\\
&=\frac1{ i\Delta}\int_{\mathbb R}\Big(\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big]*g*K_h)(x)ix+(-ix)\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big[\varphi^{-1}(-u)\big]*g*K_h)(x)\Big)P(dx)\\
&=0
\end{align}
Where am I wrong? It seems to just cancel out - maybe it's more than simple algebraic manipulations. Anyone?

Comment: There is a mess with the signs, one of them is bad in the first equation, but it appears to be ok... i am sure the author is intending to *adding* both terms for a factor of 2, instead of cancelling everything (unless indeed that is the identity he wanted to prove!)

Comment: @hyprfrco you mean in $(1)$? What makes you think so? At least that's how they derived it and it seems to be all right. To be honest, I am not entirely sure what kind of expression they actually want but it's definitely not zero...

Comment: You missed a Dirac delta term and a principal value. The correct formula is $$\mathcal{F}[g'(x)](\omega) = i \omega \mathcal{F}[g(x)](\omega), \qquad \mathcal{F}[g(x)](\omega) = PV.(\frac{ \mathcal{F}[g(x)](\omega)}{i \omega})+ \pi C \delta(\omega)$$ where $C = g(\infty)-g(-\infty)$ and $PV.$ is the principal value

Comment: @user1952009 Just to get you right, you say that (let's assume everything is well-defined), in general it's wrong to reason like: $$ \mathcal F[g(-u)](\omega)=\frac {1}{i\omega}\mathcal F[ \big( g(-u) \big)'](\omega)=-\frac 1{i\omega}\mathcal F[ g'(-u) ](\omega)$$?

Comment: @user1952009 Equality $(1)$ was shown in the paper, so there is nothing I could do about it...is your derivation based on some sort of integration by parts? thanks for having a look by the way!